# JQGrid Edittype: 'select' using dataurl returns <select> with <optgroup> not saving select value

Tags: jqgrid, optgroup

I have a JQGrid column with edittype:'Select' using dataUrl to return a  list of Accounts with  groups for the different Account groups.

My issue: when saving the row no value is passed to the editurl for my Select column. If i remove the 's a value is passed to editurl for my Select column.

Description: For my column data I return the Account Name, not the value, so when the grid loads the name is displayed.

When a line is edited (in-line editing), the dataUrl is called and the select list is displayed and my Account is selected for the rows data.

I then select a new Account from the Select list and press enter to save. The selected Account value is not passed to the editurl function for the column. if i remove the 's from the  the Account value is passed to the editurl function.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, ie not setting a grid parameter,

Hoping you can help me out.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

My Grid code:

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    var lastSelection;
    var grid = jQuery("#BankTransactions");
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: '/DropDown/GridData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['TransactionLineId', 'TransactionId', 'BankTransactionId', 'Number', 'Amount', 'Category'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'transactionLineId', index: 'transactionLineId', editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true, width: 40, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'transactionId', index: 'transactionId', editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true, width: 40, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'bankTransactionId', index: 'bankTransactionId', editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true, width: 40, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'Number', index: 'Number', width: 100, align: 'left', sortable: false },
                    { name: 'Amount', index: 'SubAmount', editable: true, width: 100, align: 'right', sortable: false, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'class="BankTranEdit"' }, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '&nbsp;'} },
                    { name: 'CategoryIdURL', index: 'CategoryIdURL',
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: 'select',
                        //formatter: 'select',
                        editoptions: { dataUrl: "/DropDown/CategorySelectList" },
                        width: 220,
                        align: 'left'
                    },
                  ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 100,
        rowList: [25, 50, 100],
        editurl: "/Dropdown/GridSave",
        sortname: 'Number',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 1250,
        height: 450,
        onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellContent, e) {
                        grid.restoreRow(lastSelection);
                        grid.editRow(rowid, true, null, null, null, null, null);
                        lastSelection = rowid;  
                      }

    });
});
```

Output of /Dropdown/GridData:

```
{"total":1,
"page":1,
"records":6,
"rows":[
    {"id":165,"cell":["165","249","125","DM000249","1500.00","Sales"]},
    {"id":145,"cell":["145","229","105","SM000229","100.00","Rent"]},
    {"id":153,"cell":["153","237","113","SM000237","38.07","Bank Fees"]},
    {"id":185,"cell":["185","269","145","SM000269","750.00","Cash Discounts"]},
    {"id":194,"cell":["194","278","154","SM000278","13.29","Rent"]},
    {"id":211,"cell":["211","295","171","SM000295","100.00","Rent"]}]
}
```

Output of /Dropdown/CategorySelectList

```
<select>
<optgroup label='Expenses'>
<option value='42'>Accounting Fees</option>
<option value='60'>Bank Fees</option>
<option value='23'>Bank Service Charges</option>
<option value='24'>Books and Publications</option>
<option value='25'>Cash Discounts</option>
<option value='43'>Rent</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label='Income'>
<option value='19'>Sales</option>
<option value='20'>Services</option>
<option value='21'>Interest Income</option>
<option value='22'>Other Income</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you modify your question and append it with the output from '/DropDown/CategorySelectList' and from '/DropDown/GridData/'. Having the data one can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I've updated the question with the requested output. Should have done so first time, my bad.

Answer (score 6):

The current version of jqGrid don't works with `<optgroup>` inside of `<select>`.

[image]

I find that the usage of `<optgroup>` could be helpful in some cases. So I debugged the jqGrid code a little and found out that one need to change only two lines of code of jqGrid (the lines [143-144](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L143) of the `grid.inlinedit.js` or the lines 8262-8263 of the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` from jqGrid 4.1.1) from

```
tmp[nm] = $("select>option:selected",this).val();
tmp2[nm] = $("select>option:selected", this).text();
```

to

```
tmp[nm] = $("select>option:selected,select>optgroup>option:selected",this).val();
tmp2[nm] = $("select>option:selected,select>optgroup>option:selected",this).text();
```

or just to

```
tmp[nm] = $("select option:selected",this).val();
tmp2[nm] = $("select option:selected",this).text();
```

to fix the problem.

If one need have support of selects having `multiple: true` attribute:

[image]

one should modify in the same way as above one more line ([line 149](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L149)) of the `grid.inlinedit.js` having the `"select>option:selected"`. To make jqGrid with `multiple: true` attribute working with `dataUrl` property one have to fix one more line (the [line 67](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L67)) of the `grid.inlinedit.js`. One need change

```
if(cm[i].edittype == "select" && cm[i].editoptions.multiple===true && $.browser.msie){
    $(elc).width($(elc).width());
}
```

to for example the following

```
if(cm[i].edittype === "select" && typeof(cm[i].editoptions)!=="undefined" &&
   cm[i].editoptions.multiple===true &&
   typeof(cm[i].editoptions.dataUrl)==="undefined" && $.browser.msie) {

    $(elc).width($(elc).width());
}
```

This change will prevent setting of the very small `width` of the select **before** it is loaded by the `$.ajax` request from `dataUrl`. Probably one should place the same fix of the `width` inside of [success](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.common.js#L349) event handler of the corresponding `$.ajax` call from `grid.common.js` where the data for `dataUrl` will be loaded. I tested my demos in IE9 and it is not needed to make the fix for IE9.

You can see the demos with the fixed jqGrid code here: [the single select demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OptGroup.htm), [the multiselect demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OptGroupMultiple.htm). You should take in the consideration, that there are no code for the "/Dropdown/GridSave"  on the server which will be used in the `editurl`. Nevertheless you will see in Fiddeler of Firebug that the posted data, which will be send to the server, do contain the information about the selected item. If you want make the demo working locally you should modify the `editurl` to 'clientArray' and probably set additionally `loadonce:true`.