# With edittype select and multiple true, select box is not loading data

Tags: jqgrid

I have select box in jqGrid and to load data m using `dataUrl`. Everything is working fine but when I put `multiple` as `true` then data is not getting displayed in the grid but in the console its printing the data. Googled a lot but couldn't find solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastsel;
    var skip = 0;
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: 'SomeActionClass.do?option=LOAD',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: [],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'generalised_skill_id', index: 'generalised_skill_id',
                width: 120, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 1 },
                editable: true, edittype: "select",
                editoptions: {
                    dataEvents: [
                        {
                            type: 'change',
                            fn: function (e) {
                                var Value = $(this).val();
                                if (Value == "CreateNew") {
                                    addSkill(Value);
                                }
                            }
                        }],
                    dataUrl: 'PopulatePrimarySkillData.do?nd=' + Math.random()
                }
            },
            { name: 'primary_skill_ids', index: 'primary_skill_ids', width: 120,
                formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 2 },
                editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, edittype: "select",
                editoptions: {
                    dataEvents: [
                        {
                            type: 'change',
                            fn: function (e) {
                                var Value = $(this).val();
                                if (Value == "CreateNew") {
                                    addSkill(Value);
                                }
                            }
                        }],
                        value: "", multiple: true, size: 3,
                    dataUrl: 'PopulatePrimarySkillData.do?nd=' + Math.random()
                }
            },
        ],
        rowNum: 25,
        rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowTotal: 10000,
        sortname: 'rgs_id',
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 600,
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiselect: true,
        mtype: "POST",
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadonce: true,
        loadComplete: function () {
            $('#list').setGridParam({ datatype: "json" });
            $('#list').trigger("filterToolbar");
            $('#list').trigger("reloadGrid");
        },
        ondblClickRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                data = jQuery('#list').getRowData(id);
                var str = data['status'];
                if (str == "Fulfilled" || str == "Canceled") {
                    alert('Fulfilled and Cancelled demands can not be edited');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true, pickdates);
                    lastsel = id;
                }
            }
        },
        editurl: 'SomeActionClass.do?option=EDITorADD'
    });
});
```

For generalised skill its loading the select box but for primary skill its not loading anything. However if I remove `multiple:true` from primary skill then its loading the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Following is my PopulatePrimarySkillData class.

```
    // In this function query to fetch all the skills from database is written.
    ArrayList primarySkillList = fetchPrimarySkills();
    StringBuilder htmlSelectString = new StringBuilder("<select> ");
    for (int i = 0; i < primarySkillList.size(); i++) {
        SkillsetBean sb = (SkillsetBean) primarySkillList.get(i);
        htmlSelectString.append("<option value='");
        htmlSelectString.append(sb.getPrimarySkillId());
        htmlSelectString.append("'>");
        htmlSelectString.append(sb.getPrimarySkillDesc());
        htmlSelectString.append("</option>");
    }
    htmlSelectString
            .append("<option value='CreateNew'>Create New</option> ");
    htmlSelectString.append("</select> ");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    System.out.println("The SELECT String is : "
            + htmlSelectString.toString());
    out.println(htmlSelectString.toString());
    return null;
```

This Function prints following result in the console.

```
 <select> <option value='1'>.Net</option>
<option value='2'>Appl packaging</option>
<option value='3'>BOXI</option>
<option value='4'>Business Analyst</option>
<option value='5'>C++</option>
<option value='6'>CNG</option>
<option value='7'>DB2</option>
<option value='8'>Flash</option>
<option value='9'>IIS Admin</option>
<option value='10'>Informatica</option>
<option value='11'>Java / J2EE</option>
<option value='12'>Java Flex</option>
<option value='13'>MS Access</option>
<option value='14'>Mainframe</option>
<option value='15'>NAT/ADABAS</option>
<option value='16'>Oracle</option>
<option value='17'>Oracle DBA</option>
<option value='18'>Others</option>
</select>
```

I think on server side there is no problem cause when I remove "multiple:true" data is getting loaded.

Here is the sample JSON data. I hope this is helpfull.

```
{"id":"166","cell":["Business Analyst","BOXI,C++"]}
{"id":"167","cell":["C++",".Net,C++"]}
{"id":"168","cell":[".Net",".Net,CNG"]}
{"id":"169","cell":["Business Analyst","Appl packaging,Business Analyst"]}
{"id":"170","cell":["Business Analyst,C++","CICS,Cobol"]}
{"id":"171","cell":[,"Appl packaging",".Net,Business Analyst"]}
{"id":"172","cell":["CNG","BOXI,Appl packaging"]}
{"id":"173","cell":["Business Analyst","Business Analyst,BOXI"]}
```

Comment: Could you include the test JSON data so that one could test your problem without having you server environment? You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to catch the server response. If your server is accessible from the internet you can just post the corresponding URL to the test page.

Comment: @Oleg I have updated the code please check.

Comment: To be able to reproduce your experiment one needs `addSkill` and some simple JSON data which generate `SomeActionClass.do?option=LOAD` to fill the jqGrid before editing. If your main problem now is the **loading** of the data you could post simplified jqGrid.

Comment: by the way the `Math.random()` from the `dataUrl: 'PopulatePrimarySkillData.do?nd=' + Math.random()` will be executed **once** at the time of jqGrid generation. You can consider to use `ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false }` instead.

Comment: @Oleg I have posted some sample data. You can delete dataEvent. Loading data in the other fields is not a problem. Everything else is working fine except for the drop down and about "ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false }" I tried that but I dint work for me. "math.random()" worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a part of problems (jqGrid bugs) which I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492100/jqgrid-edittype-select-using-dataurl-returns-select-with-optgroup-not-savi/6505546#6505546) and which I posted as [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/support-inside-of/#p23788) to the developer of jqGrid. The bugs are still not fixed so you my attempts to reproduces your problem in Internet Explorer [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Chhaya.htm):

[image]

I used IE9 for the test. If you fix the line 8217 of the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` (version 4.1.2) from

```
if(cm[i].edittype == "select" && cm[i].editoptions.multiple===true && $.browser.msie) {
```

to

```
if(cm[i].edittype === "select" && typeof(cm[i].editoptions)!=="undefined" && cm[i].editoptions.multiple===true && typeof(cm[i].editoptions.dataUrl)==="undefined" && $.browser.msie) {
```

the problem will be fixed and you will have

[image]

(See [the same demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Chhaya1.htm), but which use the fixed `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`).

Moreover I wrote you in the comment that the attempt generate unique URL used in `dataUrl` with

```
dataUrl: 'PopulatePrimarySkillData.do?nd=' + Math.random()
```

generate **one** url like

```
PopulatePrimarySkillData.do?nd=0.30184902572188804
```

If you would use `dataUrl: 'PopulatePrimarySkillData.do` and will use additional parameter `ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false }` the `dataUrl` which will be used will be really unique like

```
PopulatePrimarySkillData.do?_=1312564872215
PopulatePrimarySkillData.do?_=1312564872217 
PopulatePrimarySkillData.do?_=1312564891288
...
```

Comment: Thanks!! it worked and I have changed dataUrl: 'PopulatePrimarySkillData.do also its working fine.. Yayy.. :) :)

Comment: @Chhaya: You are welcome! I hope that my bug fix will sometime included in the original jqGrid code. At least I wrote [one more post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/support-inside-of/#p24173) in the trirand forum.