# jqGrid Multiple Select List from JOIN

Tags: jqgrid

I have 3 database tables. The first is `users`, the second is `tasks` and the third is `tasks_per_user`, where i store the relations between users and tasks. A user can have many tasks (or all) and each tasks may belong to many users.

What i want is to create in jqGrid a Multiple Selection Element, where i can list the selected tasks per user, but also be able to change it. I want the list element to present all the available tasks from the `tasks` table while present as selected the ones that are stored in the `tasks_per_user` for the specific user.
I have managed to do this for a single select element but i can't make it work for multiple.
Is this possible?

Comment: Little unclear to me. Some code will help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you need fill `tasks` column as comma separated tasks of the user. The `tasks` column column can have

```js
edittype: "select", editoptions: { multiple: true, value: "..." }
```

where the `value` or `dataUrl` provide the list of possible tasks. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Chhaya1.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960946/315935) and [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OptGroupMultiple1.htm) from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6505546/315935). I recommend you additionally to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9684882/315935) which describes a bug in IE7/IE8 with the corresponding bug fix.

Comment: Sorry guys. Stack with boss!! Thanks for the responses. What i want is to to represent the tasks for each user in the users table. Give me a minute to check the answers Oleg provided.

Comment: I have managed to create a multiple select list in the form, but all options are unchecked. How can i pass the selected values from the database join?

Comment: @Theodore: Look at the demo which I posted. If you start to *modify* list of options the current options are preselected.